# Python valueError: Couldn't parse datetime string: roving single quotes in sql

Tags: python, sql

I'm importing data into a table from a txt file which looks like:

```
 1,2019-8-24,Broccoli Chinese,17,1.57 
 2,2019-8-24,chia seeds,11,0.20
 3,2019-8-24,flax seeds,25,0.20
 4,2019-8-24,sunflower seeds,26,0.30
```

When I print the table in the python shell I get:

```
(1, '2019-8-24', 'Broccoli Chinese', 17, 1.57)
(2, '2019-8-24', 'chia seeds', 11, 0.2)
(3, '2019-8-24', 'flax seeds', 25, 0.2)
(4, '2019-8-24', 'sunflower seeds', 26, 0.3)
```

Later on when using the table I'm getting errors like

```
valueError: Couldn't parse datetime string: '2019-8-24'
```

Are those single quotes ' ' actually in the table entry? Like in the actual table is it '2019-8-24' or is it just 2019-8-24, and when I print out the row it adds the ' '.

I'm only asking as I'm having trouble sorting out the valueError, and was wondering if it might be that single quotes ' ' had somehow been entered around dates in the table during import and might need to be removed?

EDIT

this is the actual code which does not run due to the error

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret' 
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from app import FoodConsumed_Tb

rows = FoodConsumed_Tb.query.all()

for row in rows:
    consumed_food_entry_to_update = FoodConsumed_Tb.query.get_or_404(row.id)
    consumed_food_entry_to_update.date_created = datetime.strptime(consumed_food_entry_to_update.date_created, "%Y-%m-%d").date()

db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your SQL version doesn't like the month being a single digit.  You could try to scrub this data yourself using Python, e.g.

```
def repl(m):
    year = m.group(1)
    month = m.group(2).zfill(2)
    day = m.group(3).zfill(2)

    return year + '-' + month + '-' + day

date = '2019-8-24'
date_new = re.sub('(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)', repl, date)
print(date)
print(date_new)
```

This prints:

```
2019-8-24
2019-08-24
```

All I am doing here is to left pad the month and day components to two digits, using zeroes on the left.  I didn't bother to touch the year, assuming you don't expect any data from the Middle Ages.

Comment: I've tried it with 2019-08-24 first and got this error, so I was then trying it with 24-8-24, so I don't think this is the issue

Comment: What is your SQL version (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) ?

Comment: sqlite, this issue relates to the problem I've posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58388332/python-sqlite-valueerror-couldnt-parse-datetime-string

Comment: Ive just tried it and still get the error ValueError: Couldn't parse datetime string: '2019-08-24'

Comment: At this point, I think you should include the actual SQLite code which is causing this error.

Comment: just added the actual SQLite code to the end of the question

Comment: Your problem does not seem reproducible, and the call `datetime.strptime("2019-08-24", "%Y-%m-%d").date()` should be valid.

Comment: Ive reproduced my problem with a python script here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58397312/python-sqlite-error-with-parsing-datetime-string